# Pythonic array indexing with boolean masking array

Tags: python, numpy

I get a PEP8 complaint about `numpy.where(mask == False)` where mask is a boolean array. The PEP8 recommendation comparison should be either 'if condition is false' or 'if not condition'. What is the pythonic syntax for the suggested comparison inside `numpy.where()`?

Comment: What PEP8 tester are you using?  PEP8 is a general Python style recommendation.  It's not adapted to `numpy`.  Your expression looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: `mask==False` is the same as `~mask`, but quite different from `mask is False` or `not mask`.

Comment: @hpaulj I use pycharm and its native code inspection is I believe using pep8 v '1.7.0'

Comment: https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle/issues/450 is a github issue about this problem; and basically the same information as here.  In numpy this `==` is valid, and cannot be replaced with a pep8 compliant form.  So ignore the complaint.

Answer (score 1):

Negating a boolean mask array in NumPy is `~mask`.

Also, consider whether you actually need `where` at all. Seemingly the most common use is `some_array[np.where(some_mask)]`, but that's just an unnecessarily wordy and inefficient way to write `some_array[some_mask]`.

Comment: Boolean indexing takes the same amount of time as the `where` version.  I think that means there's an implicit `where`. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing

Comment: @hpaulj: IIRC, for more complex cases, NumPy does call `nonzero`, but for simple cases, it bypasses that and uses the boolean mask directly.

Comment: @hpaulj: See the `array_boolean_subscript` code in [`numpy/core/src/multiarray/mapping.c`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/mapping.c). The timings I'm getting aren't what I expected, though. On some inputs, `where` is actually faster!

Comment: Digging into the source, I think it's because [`PyArray_Nonzero`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/2aabeafb97bea4e1bfa29d946fbf31e1104e7ae0/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c#L2165) and the [1D integer array index case](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/mapping.c#L1572) are optimized to not use a `NpyIter` for the 1D case, while that optimization never made it into `array_boolean_subscript`. For 1D arrays and non-small proportions of `True` in the mask, the `NpyIter` overhead overwhelms the advantage of not needing to create an integer array...

Comment: while for 2D and up, or for small proportions of `True` in the mask, `where` loses due to the overhead of creating integer index arrays. Now I want to write up a pull request. `arr[where(mask)]` should not be outperforming `arr[mask]`.